# clear input field content that has a directive for currency format in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the first time when I am using and try to learn angular and typescript, I have an input field that I want to use a currency format directive for that and I searched and found proper directive but when the user wants to delete the input number and use backspace button, after deleting input numbers, 0 will show in input and then user have to press backspace again to clear the input field, I find  that `$filter(number)` is doing this and I use a simple code to prevent that.
here is my code

```
mymodule.directive("currency", function($filter) {
"use strict";

return {
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) {
            return;
        }

        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function() {
            return $filter("number")(ctrl.$modelValue);
        });

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            var num= viewValue.replace(/[\,\.]/g, ""),
                b = $filter("number")(num);
           // i add this if to check if the value is zero don't show  in           input
            if (b == 0) {
                elem.val("");
            } else {
                elem.val(b);
            }


            return num;
        });
    }
};
})
```

but I am not sure that this is a good idea.
Is there any other way to achieve what I want?